# How to copy messages in ZeroMQ without copying the memory?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm trying to initialize a message in ZeroMQ that I can send multiple times without copying memory every time.

According to [the documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-msg-copy), this can be done by using the `zmq_msg_copy` function (or `message_t::copy()` in C++):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <zmq.hpp>
using namespace zmq;

int main() {
    int payload = 5;
    message_t* msg = new message_t((void*)&payload, sizeof(payload));
    message_t copy = message_t(sizeof(payload));
//    msg->copy(&copy); // this fails but does not produce an error
    int status = zmq_msg_copy((zmq_msg_t*)copy.data(), (zmq_msg_t*)msg->data());
    printf("%i\n", status);
}
```

I compile with

```
gcc -lzmq -lstdc++ file.cpp
```

and run

```
./a.out
```

which produces

> -1

What am I doing wrong here?

---

As for source and destination variables:

`zmq_msg_copy` has [destination first, source second](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-msg-copy):

```
int zmq_msg_copy (zmq_msg_t *dest, zmq_msg_t *src);
```

`message_t::copy` is implemented the following way:

```
inline void copy (message_t const *msg_)
{
    int rc = zmq_msg_copy (&msg, const_cast<zmq_msg_t*>(&(msg_->msg)));
    if (rc != 0)
        throw error_t ();
}
```

so @vasek is exactly right, the supplied argument needs to be the source.

Comment: Is that the correct way to set the `char* data` (by calling `msg->data()` passed to `memcpy`) of `message_t*` ? Try setting it via constructor.

Comment: Why not use `message_t::move()`?

Comment: You're right, constructor is more natural. I changed it, but it doesn't change the outcome. I'm using `copy` and not `move` because I want to send the message more than once (added in text).

Comment: What zmq version are you using? I have 4.0.4 and under Windows result is `0` - as expected.

Comment: 4.2.2 on Archlinux, gcc 7.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation for [message_t](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-cpp) argument to `copy` should be source message, not the destination.

This code should work (tested under Slackware 14.2/GCC6.3 and MSVC 2017):

```
message_t copy;
copy.copy(msg);
```

Also note you don't have to preallocate message buffer for copied message.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. I checked this before, but must have misread. Thank you!